# Why some methods of ndarray are present as an equivalent function in top-level of numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, oop, design-patterns, numpy-ndarray

I see there is `ndarray.reshape` and also `numpy.reshape` and the documentation mentions them to be equivalent. Similarly for `ravel`. If that is the case, why did they make unnecessary duplicate of these methods in numpy namespace while also breaking one of the Zen principle

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Comment: You already posted a similar question a few minutes ago regarding `resize()`. Are you going to ask a new question for any equivilant function?

Comment: In this question both the functions have same functionality, in the previous question they had different. And that question was "why different definitions instead of a single overarching one", and this is "why multiple existence of the same thing"

Comment: You can give the function an argument like a list, which it will first convert to an array, and then use the method. So mostly the function form is a convenience.  That `zen` is not a rule.  Ultimately it comes down to choices made by developers years ago.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually `numpy.ndarray.reshape` and `numpy.reshape`, the numpy authors chose to make the `reshape` function more accessible this way. I would personally argue that `numpy.reshape` is far more obvious than the other.

Additionally this allows for different patterns:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])

# Using numpy.reshape
np.reshape(x, (1, 3))
# array([[1, 2, 3]])

# Wouldn't be possible without numpy.ndarray.reshape
x.reshape(1, 3)
# array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: If I look with the lens of OOP, method seems more obvious than function. Also, I don't know why you called the function to be more accessible. Aren't both equally accessible?  Doesn't, in the first place, one always need an array before reshaping it?